# When is the Equal Pressure Point in a Typical ICE?

Tags: automotive-engineering, vapor-pressure

My question refers to a typical bog standard normally-aspirated 4-cylinder petrol/gasoline engine.

Let's say it's a 2.0 litre engine (10:1 compression ratio, firing order 1-3-4-2) operating at 2000 rpm with 30% throttle open. Ambient conditions are 1000 millibars of pressure at 12 degrees C (285 degrees K).

When cylinder 1 is on its compression stroke (increasing pressure), cylinder 2 is on its power/expansion stroke (decreasing pressure).

Obviously, for most of the period in question, the pressure in cylinder 2 is higher than that in cylinder 1, but there is a cross-over point at which the pressures in both cylinders are the same. My question is, at what crank angle should I expect to find this equality?

If necessary, and for simplicity, assume that 100% of the petrol/gasoline has fully combusted into CO2 & H2O, but if you'd like to assume more realistic figures please do so. I doubt that it would affect the equality point too much though.

Because the equal point is obviously fairly late in cylinder 1's compression stroke, inlet valve timing is probably irrelevant. The exhaust valve timing though might be relevant, so please assume that it (they) open after the equal pressure point.

Comment: Well, of all the power plant analysis courses I took and all the books I read about engines and engine theory - Cummins, Judge, Ricardo, to name but a few - never came across this concept... pressure rise, volumetric efficiency, peak pressure, but this ??

Comment: cross-posted here : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409748. and the comment is very apt about the interest.